# $_GET variable is not being set because of .htaccess file changes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have been using '.htaccess' to rewrite how the page url should look so instead of:-

```
details.php?video=how+to+do+this&user=xxx
```

It should be more like this:-

```
/details/xxx/how+to+do+this
```

It's working and all, but here comes the issue; when I try to add a new $_GET category that wouldn't be useful all the time, that is the "page" get variable as not all video pages are going to have this variable. So when I add this variable nothing is set, it does show in the URL however.

`/details/xxx/how+to+do+this?page=2`

Here is the actual line of code that I used to rewrite one of the pages that's facing this issue.

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/(.*)$ user.php?user=$1&view=$2
```

Comment: stop trying to do routing in .htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.*)/(.*)$ user.php?user=$1&view=$2  [NC,L,QSA]
```

> **QSA|qsappend** When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to discard the existing query
>   string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the [QSA]
>   flag causes the query strings to be combined. 
>   https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/rewrite/flags.html